# How to redirect from one form view to another in odoo?

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, openerp-8

Even though button appears it does not redirect me anywhere.I want first button to redirect to sale.order form view (id 605) which contains discount and second button to sale2.order form view (id 575) which does not contain any discount to items.Should i do anything in python code or just modify my xml code?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>

    <record id="view3_order_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">sale3.order.form</field>
        <field name="model">sale.order</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Sales Order">
                <h1>Selection Panel</h1>
                    <button name="redirection1" string="Discount" type="action" class="oe_highlight"/>
                    <button name="redirection2" string="No Discount" type="action" class="oe_highlight"/>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record id="action3_orders" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Sales3 Orders</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">sale.order</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form</field>
    </record>

    <record id="redirection1" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Redirection_to_discount</field>
        <field name="res_model">sale.order</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form</field>
        <field name="res_id">605</field>
        <field name="target">current</field>
    </record>

    <record id="redirection2" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Redirection_to_no_discount</field>
        <field name="res_model">sale.order</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form</field>
        <field name="res_id">575</field>
        <field name="target">current</field>
    </record>

</data>
</openerp>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `name` for action button should actually be action's numeric id, and not action's name. Of course in reality it would be much better to use the name. To do that use the printf syntax - `%(action_name)d` instead of `action_name`. This way the name will later be replaced with a numeric id:

```
<button name="%(redirection1)d" string="Discount" type="action" class="oe_highlight"/>
<button name="%(redirection2)d" string="No Discount" type="action" class="oe_highlight"/>
```

Comment: Hey i am getting this error,                                                               Integrity Error

The operation cannot be completed, probably due to the following:
- deletion: you may be trying to delete a record while other records still reference it
- creation/update: a mandatory field is not correctly set

Comment: This doesn't seem related to this issue. Please try creating a new database in Odoo's db manager.

Comment: I am trying this in sales module, i created a new form view with just these two buttons as elements and gave lower priority number to this so that always this form loads but it is giving me this error because there are some required(mandatory) fields in the other form view like name which cannot be null. I am not getting why it is looking other forms when i have not mentioned it here.

Comment: It's doesn't matter which fields are in the view. Those required fields are still required in the data model itself, which Odoo tries to save when you click on any button in a form.